# Pandas Pivot Table List of Aggfunc

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Pandas Pivot Table Dictionary of Agg function

I am trying to calculate 3 `aggregative` functions during pivoting:

1. Count
2. Mean
3. StDev

This is the code:

```
n_page = (pd.pivot_table(Main_DF, 
                         values='SPC_RAW_VALUE',  
                         index=['ALIAS', 'SPC_PRODUCT', 'LABLE', 'RAW_PARAMETER_NAME'], 
                         columns=['LOT_VIRTUAL_LINE'],
                         aggfunc={'N': 'count', 'Mean': np.mean, 'Sigma': np.std})
          .reset_index()
         )
```

Error I am getting is: `KeyError: 'Mean'`

How can I calculate those 3 functions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `aggfunc` argument of `pivot_table` takes a function or list of functions but not `dict`

> aggfunc : function, default numpy.mean, or list of functions
>   If list of functions passed, the resulting pivot table will have hierarchical columns whose top level are the function names (inferred from the function objects themselves)

So try

```
n_page = (pd.pivot_table(Main_DF, 
                         values='SPC_RAW_VALUE',  
                         index=['ALIAS', 'SPC_PRODUCT', 'LABLE', 'RAW_PARAMETER_NAME'], 
                         columns=['LOT_VIRTUAL_LINE'],
                         aggfunc=[len, np.mean, np.std])
          .reset_index()
         )
```

You may want to rename the hierarchical columns afterwards.

Comment: Can you please advise how can i rename hierarchical columns, say "len" to "n"

Answer (score 26):

As written in approved answer by @Happy001, `aggfunc` cant take `dict` is false. we can actually pass the `dict` to `aggfunc`.

A really handy feature is the ability to pass a `dictionary` to the `aggfunc` so you can perform different functions on each of the values you select.
for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('sales-funnel.xlsx')  #loading xlsx file

table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Manager', 'Status'], columns=['Product'], values=['Quantity','Price'],
           aggfunc={'Quantity':len,'Price':[np.sum, np.mean]},fill_value=0)
table
```

In the above code, I am passing `dictionary` to the `aggfunc` and performing `len` operation on `Quantity` and `mean`, `sum` operations on `Price`.

Here is the output attaching:

[image]

The example is taken from [pivot table explained.](http://pbpython.com/pandas-pivot-table-explained.html)

Comment: Great one @ganesh. However i noticed that one value can be mapped only to once aggfunc. If you attempt to map same value with other aggfunc, only the first mapping works. Have you come across this situation?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `groupby`

```
df = (Main_DF
      .groupby(['ALIAS', 'SPC_PRODUCT', 'LABLE', 'RAW_PARAMETER_NAME'], as_index=False)
      .LOT_VIRTUAL_LINE
      .agg({'N': 'count', 'Mean': np.mean, 'Sigma': np.std})
     )
```

Setting `as_index=False` just leaves these as columns in your dataframe so you don't have to reset the index afterwards.

Comment: Seems value i am calculating statistics 'SPC_RAW_VALUE' disappeared in your code

Comment: Can you post some sample data?  `Main_DF.head().to_dict('list')`

Comment: Sorry, can't. This is IP

Comment: Then make some up! [ask]