# How to make new column based on value of raws

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file like the list below (which has thousands of rows);

```
name,location,time
james,ond,5
conor,aas,2
james,jja,3
elisa,aab,1
mike,sjs,1
elisa,ond,5
elisa,mmm,2
```

How can I turn this into (basicly make the values in second column (location) as new columns, search in the names for each and make the names don't repeat and put 0 as values on new columns if it is not there. The desired outcome with the code is:

```
name,ond,aas,jja,aab,sjs,mmm
james,5,0,3,0,0,0
conor,0,2,0,0,0,0
elisa,5,0,0,1,0,2
mike,0,0,0,0,1,0
```

What I tried so far to do this is to load it twice as two different databases and get a value but it fails all the time giving exactly the same result before.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

df1['time'] = df2['time'].where(df1[['name','location']].isin(df2).all(axis=1)).fillna('0')
```

or the below code to extract the values but still does not work:

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['name','location'], how='left').fillna(0)
```

Comment: Does this help you: [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)?

Comment: You can try: `df.pivot(index='name', columns='location', values='time').fillna(0).reset_index()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(index=df['name'], columns=df['location'], values=df['time'], aggfunc=lambda x: x).\
            fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
location    name    aab aas jja mmm ond sjs
0          conor    0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1          elisa    1.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 5.0 0.0
2          james    0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 5.0 0.0
3           mike    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

Here `location` is the column name, you can get rid of it via `df.columns.name = None`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one is the solution you are looking for:

Given the dataframe `df`

```
    name location  time
0  james      ond     5
1  conor      aas     2
2  james      jja     3
3  elisa      aab     1
4   mike      sjs     1
5  elisa      ond     5
6  elisa      mmm     2

import pandas as pd
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='time', index='name', columns='location', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
location  aab  aas  jja  mmm  ond  sjs
name                                  
conor       0    2    0    0    0    0
elisa       1    0    0    2    5    0
james       0    0    3    0    5    0
mike        0    0    0    0    0    1
```

Note that if you have different values for the same combination of `name` and `location`, you have to select an appropriate `aggfunc`, to properly display the value you need. Ypu can also pass a `dictionary` to the aggfunc value, as explained in [Discussion on aggfunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193862/pandas-pivot-table-list-of-aggfunc)